# Echo 404 directly from nginx to improve performance

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am in charge of production servers serving static content for a website. Those servers are constantly being crawled by bots looking for potential exploits (*which isn't that much of a problem security-wise because no application can be reached behind the web server*) but 
generates thousands of `404` per day, sometimes per hour. I am looking into ways of blocking those requests but it's tricky (*you want to make sure you don't block legitimate traffic and these bots are becoming more and more clever at looking like they're legit*) and is going to take me a while to find an acceptable solution.

In the meantime I would like to reduce the performance impact of serving those `404` pages. Indeed we're using `nginx` which by default is configured to serve it's `404` page from the disk *(This can be changed using the [`error_page`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page) directive but in the end the `404` will either have to be served from disk or from another external source (e.g. upstream application which would be worst))* which isn't ideal.

I ran a test with `ab` on my local machine with a basic configuration: in one case I `echo` a message directly from `nginx` so the disk isn't touched at all, in the other case I hit a missing page and `nginx` serves its `404` from disk.

```
server {
  # [...] the default nginx stuff
  location / {

  }
  location /this_page_exists {
     echo "this page was found";
  }
}
```

Here are the test results (*my laptop has Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM + SSD in case you're wondering why they are so high*):

```
$ ab -n 500000 -c 1000 http://localhost/this_page_exists
Requests per second:    25609.16 [#/sec] (mean)

$ ab -n 500000 -c 1000 http://localhost/this_page_doesnt_exists
Requests per second:    22905.72 [#/sec] (mean)
```

As you can see, returning a value with `echo` is `11%` ((25609−22905)÷22905×100) faster than serving the `404` page from disk. Accordingly I would like to `echo` a simple `404 Page not Found` string from `nginx`.

I tried many things so far but they all failed, essentially the idea was this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri @not_found;
}
location @not_found {
  echo "404 - Page not found";
}
```

The problem is that as soon as the [`echo` directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule#echo) is used, the `http response code` is set to `200`. I tried changing that by doing `error_page 200 = 400` but that breaks the configuration.

**How can I serve a `404` page directly from nginx? (without hacking the source which may be might next step)**

Comment: Have you considered using fail2ban to catch and then block these at the firewall ?

Comment: It's one of the options I'm looking into but I'm really clueless about it, therefore installing/testing properly + releasing into production is going to take a while. As I said before echoing a `404` would be a `In the meantime` solution (which could turn out to be worthy of the effort in my opinion).

Comment: @MDMarra: my question is about serving `404` from `nginx` directly instead of the `disk` so as to improve `performance`, and you removed the `404`, `disk`, and `performance` tags I had set, why?

Comment: Because they're bad tags and no one should use them. All three are ambiguous and add nothing to the categorization of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, by default, nginx generates a 404 response internally.  It only serves a file from disk if you tell it to using an error_page directive.  If you want to control the format of the 404 page, instead of `echo "404 - page not found";`, you can use `return 404 "404 - page not found";` (assuming you're using a somewhat recent version of nginx, I belive you need 0.9 or newer)

Comment: I've tested and it works. I was able to achieve `25329 req/sec` with that `404` method so there is definitely a performance improvement compared with the default 404.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx [echo](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule) module is what you need. But you should use it with error_page:

```
error_page 404 @echo_404;
location @echo_404 { echo "Not found"; }
```

You can make nginx close active connection by [returning 444](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#return):

```
return 444;
```

This will close socket immediately without writing anything to the net.

The difference in your calculations is just a result of [open_file_cache](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#open_file_cache) been not enabled. If you want it go faster tweak your system: accept filters, socket queue and buffers and so.

Comment: About the `echo`: I already tried it but as soon as I use `echo` the response code changes to `200`. About the `444`: that's even better performance wise (`28216 req/sec`), but I think returning a 404 is still important in that case as some genuine clients might try to access non-existing resources (broken links) in which case a 404 might be nicer than terminating the connection without returning any data